# How can I dereference a void* in C?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

I have an array of `void*`s called `bins`. Each `void*` points to a *chunk*.

#### Chunks

Each chunk consists of three things laid out one after the other in contiguous memory:

1. The size in bytes of the chunk. This is represented by a `uint32_t`.
2. The address of the next valid chunk. This is represented by a `void*`.
3. The data of the chunk. For all intents and purposes this is garbage and can be ignored.

#### What I Want to Do

My algorithm works like this:

```
if bins[index] == NULL: foo()
otherwise:
    save the address of this chunk (it is bins[index])
    get the address of the next chunk
    set bins[index] to the address of the next chunk
    return the original value bins[index] that we saved
```

I'm having a lot of trouble with getting the address of the next chunk. Right now, my implementation works, but it is *very* hacky:

```
void* next = (void*)*(uint64_t*)(bin[index] + sizeof(uint32_t));
```

The main issue is casting the address `bin[index] + sizeof(uint32_t)` to a `uint64_t` before dereferencing it. Is there any way to just dereference this as if it were an address, or a pointer?

Comment: Are your chunks `struct`s? That could help.

Comment: You can't dereference a void* you need to cast it back to whatever it was before to dereference it. Your chunks should be encapsulated in a struct and then you can cast back to that. You also have duplicated effort. The size of the chunk and the address of the next chunk tell you the same thing. It would be better to hold only the size.

Comment: You would have to use a `void` object. This is not possible in C. Your have an XY problem. No offence, but please first make up your mind what you actually want to accomplish and learn more about pointers (e.g. read a C book); you seem to be quite confused what you actually want and how C can support you with that.

Comment: You will have trouble making an array of different sized items. You may have to `malloc` the chunks and then hold an array of pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a structure with 2 members and cast the pointer:

```
struct chunk_head {
    uint32_t size;
    void *next;
};

void *next = ((struct chunk_head*)bins[index])->next;
```

This assumes `void*` is aligned on 32 bits.

A more direct but less readable way is this:

```
void *next = *(void**)((uint64_t*)bins[index] + 1);
```

Your approach is non portable as it relies on `void*` arithmetic which is a gcc extension.  Standard C does not allow adding a number to a `void*`.  Note also that you read a pointer to `uint32_t` and cast that to a `void*`, which is not exactly the same as casting the address as a `void**` and dereferencing it to read the `void*` pointer:

```
void *next = *(void**)(bin[index] + sizeof(uint32_t));  // gcc extension
```